# Is there any possibility to increase a method execution time by delegating a few threads to that method?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, performance, threadpool

As far as I know the usage of Task in c# with creation option of TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning creates a new task which behaves like a thread.

If I have method A and create for example 8 tasks and pass that method as a delegate to force them to invoke that method, then every single task will invoke method A separately, on top of that every single task and it's method has a copy of the stack so if there is any operation inside of that method which uses variables declared in that method then there is no concurrency and it doesn't affect with speeding up execution time.

The result is that 8 tasks execute the same method 8 times simultaneously in the same time as 1 single thread would do the same.

My goal is to make the method execute 8 times faster when using 8 tasks comparing to the same method executed by 1 task.

Is there any chance of doing it? I haven't been able to find any real example yet.

Comment: You don't tend to be able to achieve parallelism based gains (and they rarely scale precisely 1-1 with number of threads used) if you've got an existing method that you're treating as a black box. You would need to modify the internals of the method, and that would depend on the specifics, of which there are none in the question.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever
So is it just cutting down on some "iterations" inside of that method depending on the number of threads to ensure that the method's getting less data to compute? for example with 1 thread 1k iterations but for 8 threads 1k/8 iterations, then run that method on every single thread and wait until all tasks get completed?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever If I didn't get it, give me more details if you can please

Comment: *"My goal is to make the method execute 8 times faster when using 8 tasks comparing to the same method executed by 1 task."* -- So currently you are calling one method once, and you are asking if it's possible to make this single call 8 times faster by using 8 threads, without making any change to the method at all?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I mean with changes by giving smaller work load to that method. For example 1 task should iterate 1k times if I run it on 1 task and save the result. Then create 8 tasks, split workload at 8 small packages, give each package to the task as a parameter to the method and run that method with every single task:

1st test -> 1k iterations, run on 1 task
2nd test -> 1k iterations on 8 tasks = every single task with 1/8 of total iteations

Comment: Most methods don't accept an adjustable volume of work as argument. A method with such an argument implies that it was designed with parallelization in mind. In which case your question basically becomes "does parallelization works at reducing execution time in some scenarios?". To which the answer is obviously "yes", otherwise the [`Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel) class would not exist. I find it unlikely that you'll be satisfied with a simple "yes" answer though. Most likely you want to know something more specific. Please ask for it.

Comment: "`TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` creates a new task which behaves like a thread" - No, that's not true.

Answer (score 0):

The long story short: it depends. Depends upon a workload your method is dealing with. There are two main categories: so called "IO-bound", which is all about talking to external independent devices like a network card or a disk and awaiting for them to get ready (meanwhile CPU has no useful instructions to perform, so the `nop` instruction literally wastes all the clock cycles); the other category is known as "CPU-bound" - it is concerned with number cracking, avoids talking to external devices and even RAM, heavily relies upon CPU caches and registers (hashing or compression are good examples).

The way you parallel execution is dictated by the kind of workload you have. If you want a good advice on how to speed up your **particular** code, then show us the code in mind. Please update the post and we'll see.